# how the custom argument of PHP function is implemented in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

We write a custom function's arguments in PHP like this:

```
function something ($arg = "")
{
  // then do something
}
```

How this should be done in jquery?

this seems not to work:

```
function jq_something ($arg = "")
{

}
```

Comment: you mean this comes and a deficiency in jquery?

Comment: It's simply not a part of JavaScript's language syntax to do this, regardless if it's any of the large helper libraries such as jQuery, MooTools or Prototype - this is the same for other language features such as Type hinting etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some like this

```
function jq_something (arg) {
   arg = typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : 'default_value';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check within the function:

```
function jq_something($arg) {
    if ($arg === undefined) $arg = ""; // your default value
}
```

There is no default value syntax in JavaScript. (This has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery, by the way.)

> I thought jquery throws error on cases of missing to put an arg when a function is called –  Mostafa Talebi 1 min ago

You keep confusing jQuery with JavaScript. jQuery is just a library! There is no special syntax that jQuery defines; it is not a separate programming language. In any case, no, in JavaScript you can pass more or less arguments just fine:

```
function test(a) {
    console.log(a);
}
test("test");  // logs "test"
test();        // logs undefined
test(1, 2, 3); // logs 1
```

Of course, if you wanted, you *could* throw an error when there is the wrong amount of arguments:

```
function threeArgs(a, b, c) {
    if (arguments.length !==  threeArgs.length) throw new Error("Incorrect number of arguments");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I thought jquery throws error on cases of missing to put an arg when a function is called

Comment: @MostafaTalebi not at all, Javascript is very lenient with arguments. You can pass more arguments than the function expects, or less, without any errors.

Comment: @Doorknob Is there a reason to use a check `if ($arg === undefined) $arg = "";` rather than `$arg = $arg || 'default val'`?

Comment: @DennisMartinez what if you want to permit some _falsy_ values, such as `''`, `0` or `null`?

Comment: @DennisMartinez The first one replaces $arg with the default value only if $arg was undefined. The second does it for any falsy value, including `0`, `null`, `''`(empty string), etc.

Comment: @Tibos and @PaulS Oh wow, for some reason I always thought that `$arg = $arg || 'fallback val'` only fell back if `$arg` was `undefined`. I can see the point now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not a limitation of *jQuery* but entirely not implemented in *JavaScript* (with perhaps the exception of ES6).

Current practices are to check for *undefined* or some **unexpected** falsy value, then modify to the default.

```
function foo(x) {
    if (undefined === x) x = 0;
    return x;
}
foo('a');       // "a"
foo(1);         // 1
foo();          // 0
foo(null);      // null
foo(undefined); // 0
```

Comment: `foo(undefined);` should returns `undefined` i guess. That's why checking for `typeOf x` looks more accurate here. But for sure that's depend of what OP is looking for, anyway +1

Comment: @A.Wolff `typeof undefined; // "undefined"`, the real reason people use `typeof` is because `undefined` did not used to be immutable in the global namespace, but it now has been for some time.

Comment: My bad! Of course you are rigth. Cheking for arguments.length could be a solution for a 'non' problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think, that the following approach (as shown in my example code) can help you:

```
   function say_smth(options) {
       var defaults = {"message":"hi", "user" : "Anonymous"};

       if(undefined===options) 
           options = {}

       for (key in defaults) 
           if(undefined===options[key]) options[key]=defaults[key];


       alert (options['message'] + ', ' + options['user']);
   }
   say_smth(); //hi, Anonymous
   say_smth({"user":"Peter"}); //hi, Peter
   say_smth({"message":"nice hat"}); //nice hat, Anonymous
   say_smth({"message":"go fish", "user":"Jack"});//go fish, Jack
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support this for now. Though you could use next approaches:

1. Check if argument passed:

   ```
   function myFunc(name, gender) {
       name = name || 'unnamed';
       gender = gender || 'male';
   }
   ```
2. Use `options` object argument (for more complicated code) and have defaults pre-set for not passed options.

   ```
   var Person,
       mary;

   Person = function(name, options) {
       this.name = name;
       this.setOptions(options || {});
   };

   Person.defaultOptions = {
       age: 30,
       gender: 'male'
   };

   Person.prototype.setOptions = function(options) {
       this.options = $.extend({}, Person.defaultOptions, options);
   };

   mary = new Person('Mary', {gender: 'female'});

   console.log(mary);
   ```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/kFF8C/)